# How do I route (send) mail through a WireGuard Tunnel when sending email from one of my self-hosted domains?

Tags: ubuntu, tunnel, postfix, pfsense, wireguard

The Issue:  Mail is not going OUT over the WireGuard tunnel.

The Question: How do I configure the mail server or pfSense to use the WireGuard tunnel when sending email from one of my self-hosted domains?

The Overview: Self-hosting a web server and a mail server. Using a VPS (running pfSense) to provide two public IP address. A WireGuard tunnel is connecting the two public IP address to my self-hosted servers behind my local pfSense box. The web server and mail servers are accessible from the internet.

EDIT 1

```
                        Internet

                          / \
                           |
                          \ /
  
                  REMOTE VPS pfSense

 111.111.111.111 WAN Public IP Gateway WANGW 111.111.111.1
 222.222.222.22 Public IP NAT 1:1 192.168.3.2 Gateway VIPGW
 222.222.222.25 Public IP NAT 1:1 192.168.4.2 Gateway VIPGW
 10.6.210.0 Private WireGuard Interface WG_HOME

   GATEWAYS: WANGW      INTERFACES: WAN
             VIPGW                  WG_HOME
             WG_HOME_GW
 

                         / \
                          |
                         \ /    
                   10.6.210.0 VPS

                  WireGuard Tunnel

                   10.6.210.1 PEER
                        / \
                         |
                        \ /
       |-----------------
       |
       |
      \ /
     HOME pfSense <-----> Local ISP Gateway <-----> Internet

  100.100.100.100 WAN CGNAT Gateway WANGW 100.100.100.1
  192.168.1.1 LAN
  192.168.3.1 VLAN3
  192.168.4.1 VLAN4

GATEWAYS: WANGW     INTERFACES: WAN
          VIPGW                 LAN
          WG_VPS_GW             VLAN3
                                VLAN4
      / \
       |
      \ /

        24 Port Switch
          / \  / \   
        vlan3  vlan4
           |    |    
           |    |    
           |    |   
           |   \ / 
           | (VM HOST) enp4s0f1 / br1 192.168.4.2
           |                      |
           |                      |
           |          VM Mail Server 192.168.4.3 
           |
          \ /
   (VM HOST) enp4s0f0 / br0 192.168.3.2
       |
       |
     VM Web Server 192.168.3.3
```

Edit 2

The firewall on the VPS pfSense is blocking the mail from being sent from VM Mail Server.

FIREWALL LOG on VPS

```
X Aug 30 13:03:48   WG_HOME     10.6.210.1:12345    172.253.122.26:25   TCP:S
```

The source address is being rewritten from 192.168.4.3 (Mail Server VM) to 10.6.210.1 (Peer of WireGuard tunnel)  Because of this the firewall is blocking it.

EDIT 3

SUCCESS! SOLVED! THANKS!

The sticking point aka problem aka user error was outbound NAT.

When you said "do not NAT WG_VPS" and "do not NAT WG_HOME" I was like okay I will not NAT them.  'crickets chirping' Did not realizing that there was an option HYBRID Do Not NAT for select Interface.

QUESTION: Should I define the PORT in the SOURCE or DESTINATION in the Advanced Outbound NAT entry?

QUESTION: Can you explain why use both of the following rules.

```
pass VLAN4 inbound source 192.168.4.2 TCP port 25 -> gateway WG_VPS_GW

pass VLAN4 inbound source 192.168.4.2 destination TCP port 25 -> gateway WG_VPS_GW
```

QUESTION: Is there anything else I should consider or it is just a matter of "rinse & repeat" for setting up 587,465 if needed.

Regarding HTTP/HTTPS (192.168.3.3) are not incoming request sent out the same gateway they entered automagiclly eliminating the need to do a similarly configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core thing you need is policy routing: you need a policy routing rule to route outbound packets with a TCP destination port of 25 through the WireGuard interface. But you also need your WireGuard connection set up so that it routes packets back and forth through the tunnel without any NAT.

## pfSense to pfSense

### pf VPS

With the pfSense to pfSense WireGuard connection you've diagrammed, this is what you want on the pf VPS side:

#### WireGuard

- Make sure you've configured the "AllowedIPs" setting for the HOME endpoint to include all the destination IP addresses of traffic you may send from the pf VPS to the pf HOME: `10.6.210.1, 192.168.3.0/24, 192.168.4.0/24`
- Make sure you've assigned a pfSense interface (WG_HOME) to the WireGuard interface, created a gateway (WG_HOME_GW) for it, and made this gateway the WG_HOME interface's "Upstream Gateway" (which makes WG_HOME a WAN-type interface; see the [WAN vs LAN Interfaces](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/interfaces/wanvslan.html) documentation for the significance of this).

#### 1:1 NAT

- Make sure you've added a 1:1 NAT mapping for your web server and mail server:

  - `222.222.222.22` -> `192.168.3.2`
  - `222.222.222.25` -> `192.168.4.2`

#### Outbound NAT

- Select "Hybrid Outbound NAT", and add a custom "Do Not NAT" rule that prevents any outbound NAT from WG_HOME:

  - Do Not NAT: selected
  - Interface: WG_HOME
  - TCP/IP Version: IPv4
  - Protocol: any
  - Source address: any
  - Destination address: any

#### Static Routes

- Make sure you've added a static route for each HOME network that you want to route from the pf VPS:

  - `192.168.3.0/24` -> `WG_HOME_GW`
  - `192.168.4.0/24` -> `WG_HOME_GW`

#### Firewall Rules

###### Inbound Connections WAN -> WG_HOME

- Make sure you have a firewall rule on the WAN interface for each port that you want to allow through, using the destination IP address after 1:1 NAT translation:

  - pass in quick on WAN inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.3.2 port = http
  - pass in quick on WAN inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.3.2 port = https
  - pass in quick on WAN inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.4.2 port = smtp
  - pass in quick on WAN inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.4.2 port = smtps
  - pass in quick on WAN inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.4.2 port = submissions
- Or if you want to do the port filtering elsewhere (like on the HOME side), just add a rule for each destination IP address after 1:1 NAT translation:

  - pass in quick on WAN inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.3.2
  - pass in quick on WAN inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.4.2

###### Outbound Connections WG_HOME -> WAN

- To make sure new connections initiated by your mail server (and web server, if at some point you start sending new connections from the web sever through the WG tunnel) use the correct outbound gateway (if different than your WAN gateway), add a policy-routing firewall rule for each that routes traffic from them out your VIPGW gateway:

  - pass in quick on WG_HOME route-to VIPGW inet proto tcp from 192.168.3.2 to any
  - pass in quick on WG_HOME route-to VIPGW inet proto tcp from 192.168.4.2 to any

### pf HOME

This is what you want on the pf HOME side:

#### WireGuard

- Make sure you've configured the "AllowedIPs" setting for the VPS endpoint to include the whole IPv4 address space: `0.0.0.0/0`
- Same as with the pf VPS, make sure you've assigned a pfSense interface (WG_VPS) to the WireGuard interface, created a gateway (WG_VPS_GW) for it, and made this gateway the WG_VPS_GW interface's "Upstream Gateway".

#### Outbound NAT

- Same as with the pf VPS, select "Hybrid Outbound NAT", and add a custom "Do Not NAT" rule that prevents any outbound NAT from WG_VPS:

  - Do Not NAT: selected
  - Interface: WG_VPS
  - TCP/IP Version: IPv4
  - Protocol: any
  - Source address: any
  - Destination address: any

#### Firewall Rules

###### Inbound Connections WG_VPS -> VLAN3/4

- Make sure you have a firewall rule on the WG_VPS interface for each port that you want to allow through:

  - pass in quick on WG_VPS inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.3.2 port = http
  - pass in quick on WG_VPS inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.3.2 port = https
  - pass in quick on WG_VPS inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.4.2 port = smtp
  - pass in quick on WG_VPS inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.4.2 port = smtps
  - pass in quick on WG_VPS inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.4.2 port = submissions
- Or if you want to do the port filtering elsewhere (like on the VPS side, or on the mail/web servers themselves), just add a rule for each destination IP address:

  - pass in quick on WG_VPS inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.3.2
  - pass in quick on WG_VPS inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.4.2

###### Replies to Inbound Connections

- In an earlier edit, I said that you also needed an outbound policy-routing rule like the following, thinking that was what was needed for replies -- *that was wrong*. As long as WG_VPS is a WAN-type interface, the correct "reply-to" setting is automatically generated for inbound connections, *so you don't actually need this*:

  - pass in quick on VLAN4 route-to WG_VPS_GW inet proto tcp from 192.168.4.2 port = smtp to any

###### Outbound Connections VLAN4 -> WG_VPS

- To make sure new connections initiated by your mail server to other mail servers use the correct outbound gateway, add a policy-routing firewall rule that routes traffic for each port that that your own mail server might connect to on other mail servers:

  - pass in quick on VLAN4 route-to WG_VPS_GW inet proto tcp from 192.168.4.2 to any port = smtp
  - pass in quick on VLAN4 route-to WG_VPS_GW inet proto tcp from 192.168.4.2 to any port = smtps
  - pass in quick on VLAN4 route-to WG_VPS_GW inet proto tcp from 192.168.4.2 to any port = submissions
- You need these above outbound rules only if your mail server *initiates connections to* those remote ports -- not if it merely *listens for connections from* remote servers to those local ports. Specifically, if you don't need to connect to remote ports 587 & 465, you don't need the last 2 rules (usually you would only need 1 of the 3).

## pfSense to Linux

In a hypothetical alternative scenario where your mail server itself had a direct WireGuard connection to your pf VPS, and you did a 1:1 NAT on the pf VPS from the mail server's public IP to the mail server's WireGuard IP address, and the mail server was running Linux, you'd configure WireGuard on the mail server something like this:

```
# /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf

# local settings for the mail server
[Interface]
PrivateKey = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEE=
Address = 10.6.210.4/24
Table = 123

# route replies to inbound connections back out the WG tunnel
PreUp = ip rule add from 10.6.210.0 table 123 priority 456
PostDown = ip rule del from 10.6.210.0 table 123 priority 456

# route new connections to TCP port 25 out the WG tunnel
PreUp = ip rule add dport 25 ipproto tcp table 123 priority 457
PostDown = ip rule del dport 25 ipproto tcp table 123 priority 457

# remote settings for the VPS server
[Peer]
PublicKey = fE/wdxzl0klVp/IR8UcaoGUMjqaWi3jAd7KzHKFS6Ds=
Endpoint = 111.111.111.111:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

This policy routing rule is what would send new connections to TCP port 25 out the WG tunnel:

```
ip rule add dport 25 ipproto tcp table 123 priority 457
```

Comment: "you already have 90% of what you need set up." it seems the 10% has me chasing my tail.

Comment: I am using pfSense-to-pfSense WireGuard connection.  Mail server host is on VLAN2 so I added firewall following rule to VLAN2 [ipv4/TCP * * * 25 WGVPS] WGVPS is the VPS end of the tunnel and is 10.6.210.0 also added rules for 465 & 587.  On VPS WG rule [ipv4/TCP * * * 25 PublicIPGateway]  I am using 1:1 NAT on the VPS do I need to setup Outbound NAT translation on the VPS?    Still no joy do you see my error?

Comment: UPDATE:  Firewall rule on VPS pfSense blocking the OUTBOUND.  

X Aug 29 15:17:49  WG_LOCAL  10.6.210.1:xxxx  142.251.16.27:25  TCP:S

X Aug 29 15:17:47  WG_LOCAL  10.6.210.1:xxxx  142.251.16.27:25  TCP:S

On VPS I added to allow the SMTP traffic

[ipv4/TCP (WG-LOCAL net) * * 25(SMTP) Public-IP-GW]

SMTP was NOT blocked BUT the mail still did not go out.

Comment: Notice that the IP address of the SOURCE is 10.6.2.1 which is the local peer IP of the WireGuard tunnel and not the private IP address of the mail server host.  How can I convert that to the 192.168.4.3 address and then to its public IP address.

Comment: See my edited answer. If you want to share more details about your servers or what you've tried, please edit your question and add the details to it (then add a comment to my answer to notify me).

Comment: Justin, have added network diagram. I appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Added firewall log entry from VPS pfSense.

Comment: Thank you for the diagram -- I updated my answer to match its IP addresses and interface names. You still need to turn off outbound NAT for the WireGuard interface on your pf HOME.

Comment: Thanks Justin.  Your guidance and instruction solved my issue.  Outbound NAT was my sticking point.  Please see Edit 3.  Also when I marked as solved will that lock this post from any further comments?

Comment: I edited and expanded my answer further to try cover your follow-up questions, as well as to detail the complete configuration you'd need for pfSense <-> pfSense with both the mail server and web server and additional ports. You can still comment (and edit) after marking as solved (but consider posting a new question if it's not just a matter of further clarifications to this question or answer).